# How to differentiate parameters from other functions when instantiating an anonymous class in Scala?

Tags: scala, ambiguity

I have an abstract class A such as this one:

```
abstract class A {
  def id: String
}
```

I would like to use the companion object of A to return an instantiated anonymous subclass of A. Unfortunately, the following function does not work due to an ambiguity on `id`:

```
object A {
  def apply(id: String): A = new A { def id = id }
}
```

A simple way to hack this would be to use an intermediate variable:

```
object A {
  def apply(id: String): A = {
    val tmp = id
    new A { def id = tmp }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to break this ambiguity without changing the name of the parameter/function?

Thanks !

Comment: I believe the answer is no.

Comment: For code i've read the convention seems to be to just name the argument for your apply method `_id` or `forId`. Just curious, why do you not wish to change the name of the argument?

Comment: Thanks for the convention tips ! I basically wanted to maintain some consistency between the name of the symbols used in my API.

Answer (score 0):

I would define the object like this, or something similar, which reduces your hack by one line.

```
object A {
  def apply(idC: String): A = {
    new A { def id = idC }
  }
}
```